# MATLAB, Getting user input from string to matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, input

```
A = (32:127);
S = char(A);
S = reshape(S,32,3)'



prompt = {'Enter a sentence you would like to Encrypt'};
dlg_title = 'Input';
num_lines = 1;
defaultans = {'Hello'};
answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,defaultans);
```

Im writing a simple Encryption application for a class im in. I need to use matrices to do so. I got the user to input something into a string but how do I get them to enter it into a matrix or convert the string into a matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
prompt = 'Enter a sentence you would like to Encrypt';
dlg_title = 'Input';
num_lines = 1;
defaultans = {'Hello'};
answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,defaultans);

answer = answer{1}; % Coverts cell to String like hungptit said

% find out how big the square matrix for data should be
for i = 1:length(answer) % it should never run this far anyway
   if (i^2) > length(answer) 
       break;
   end
end

mat_len = i; 

% predefine square matrix of numbers forcing matrixA to number type
matrixA = zeros(mat_len,mat_len); 

% iterate through square matrix assigning answer values to positions
for i = 1:mat_len
    for j = 1:mat_len
        if (((i-1)*mat_len)+j) <= length(answer)
            matrixA(i,j) = answer(((i-1)*mat_len)+j);
        else
            break;
        end
    end
end
```

This is an edited answer showing a further step after the original question as answered.

"MatrixA" will be a square matrix with each letter in the input assigned to a position in the matrix then forced into being a number.

You can now process the numbers for your encryption.

Comment: is it possible to make a for loop or something of the sorts to put each character into a separate matrix? like Matrix A, so that I can get the inverse and transpose of those characters?

Comment: Yes that is possible. What size of matrix were you thinking?

Comment: I reanswered the question, I put the code below

Comment: It might be worth a new question because I cannot format code in comments but I have a solution.

Comment: I cannot write a new question.

Comment: Could you write a new answer?

Comment: I edited the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

inputdlg function will return [a cell array of string](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputdlg.html?searchHighlight=inputdlg). You can convert inputdlg's returned value to a string using below command:

```
answer = answer{1}
```

Comment: How would I put that into a matrix?

Comment: A MATLAB string is a vector of characters, which is a matrix. What is your expected output data type? If you want to convert to a int32 data type  then you can use this command x = int32(answer).

Comment: Yes but I want every character to be in their own element in the matrix

Comment: @Zipcoder that's what a character array is.

Comment: It is saying Conversion to int32 from cell is not possible.